# Error to register and login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText email,name,password;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference userIdRef;
    ProgressDialog registerDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat_users");
      //  mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        registerDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        registerDialog.setMessage("Registering..");
    }
    public void submit(View view) {
        registerDialog.show();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isComplete())
                {
                    registerDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userIdRef=databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString());
                    userIdRef.child("name").setValue(name.getText().toString());
                    finish();
                }
                registerDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: userIdRef=databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString());    here shows error

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error in the registration process, some examples are because of the password's length is not long enough and the `Password` authentication is not enabled yet in the Firebase Console.

You can catch the error by modifying the `onComplete` method implementation to

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Register success
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            userIdRef = databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            userIdRef.child("name").setValue(name.getText().toString());
            finish();
        } else {
            // If register fails
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration Error: " + task.getException(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        registerDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because you are using in your code `a null object reference`. So in order to solve this, i suggest you using the following code in which you can correctly instantiate, check for nullity and use the `firebaseUser` object.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
            //Do what you want with it
        }
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.